# How to convert elements in a list of list to lowercase?

Tags: python

I am trying to convert the elements of a list of list of lowercase. This is what is looks like.

```
print(dataset)
[['It', 'went', 'Through', 'my', 'shirt', 'And', 'came', 'out', 'The', 'back', 'and', 'hit', 'the', 'kid', 'behind', 'me', 'in', 'the', 'toe']]
```

I have tried doing this:

```
for line in dataset:
    rt=[w.lower() for w in line]
```

However this gives me an error saying list object has no attribute lower().

Comment: The specific problem described in the question here was not reproducible.

Answer (score 12):

You have a *nested structure*. Either unwrap (if there is just one list contained, ever) or use a nested list comprehension:

```
[[w.lower() for w in line] for line in dataset]
```

The nested list comprehension handles each `list` in the `dataset` list separately.

If you have just *one* list contained in `dataset`, you may as well unwrap:

```
[w.lower() for w in dataset[0]]
```

This produces a list with the lowercased strings directly contained, without further nesting.

Demo:

```
>>> dataset = [['It', 'went', 'Through', 'my', 'shirt', 'And', 'came', 'out', 'The', 'back', 'and', 'hit', 'the', 'kid', 'behind', 'me', 'in', 'the', 'toe']]
>>> [[w.lower() for w in line] for line in dataset]
[['it', 'went', 'through', 'my', 'shirt', 'and', 'came', 'out', 'the', 'back', 'and', 'hit', 'the', 'kid', 'behind', 'me', 'in', 'the', 'toe']]
>>> [w.lower() for w in dataset[0]]
['it', 'went', 'through', 'my', 'shirt', 'and', 'came', 'out', 'the', 'back', 'and', 'hit', 'the', 'kid', 'behind', 'me', 'in', 'the', 'toe']
```

Comment: Can't you shorten the inner loop to `map(str.lower,line)`?

Comment: @Falko: in Python 2, yes. In Python 3, you'd have to add `list()` to that. I prefer a list comprehension here, anyway, I find it more readable. The list comprehension would also support a mix of `str` and `unicode` objects out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Either use `map`

```
map(str.lower,line)
```

Or list comprehension (which is basically syntactic sugar)

```
[x.lower() for x in line]
```

And this process can be nested for the entire dataset

```
[[x.lower() for x in line] for line in dataset]
```

And if you want to join all lines into one, use `reduce`:

```
reduce(list.__add__,[[x.lower() for x in line] for line in dataset])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to convert all the Strings in your list in Python, you can simply use following code:

```
[w.lower() for w in My_List]
```

`My_List` is your list name